# Keep getting logged out of SO

Tags: support

I've never had an issue with SO before but I've been logged out twice in the last 24h. What's going on? Is this sitewide or just for me, any ideas what's causing it? Thanks

Comment: Logged out again! What's going on StackExchange?!