# Why does the Stack Overflow site keep logging me out? Only in Chrome

Tags: discussion, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

For the past few months, I've encountered this issue. As I do not bother until recently, I find it very annoying. I have not done any changes towards my account, nor Chrome settings.

Here are some observations:

1. It logs me out after some period of time when I do not access Stack Overflow
2. I do not get log out even if I open multi-tab of Stack Overflow at one time.

These are the environments I'm using...

1. Chrome Version 111.0.5563.110 (Official Build) (arm64)
2. MacBook. [macOS v13.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) (22A400)

I've tried..

1. Reset Chrome settings back to default, which **does not help**.
2. Log in to my Stack Overflow account using Firefox, which I **do not experience auto log out** like Chrome. Hence this scope down the issue with Chrome only.
3. Sign out existing Chrome profile and re-sign in to Chrome profile using same email.

Appreciate if one could help with this.

### Updates 29 Mar - Working!

I actually found out a way not to get myself kicked out from Stack Overflow while using chrome. I tried using "Guest" profile within Chrome and for the past 12h++ I'm still here.

Looks like it has something to do with the Chrome Profile.

[image]

Comment: Related: [I keep getting logged out of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386901/i-keep-getting-logged-out-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: I think, that your problem is with the browser, not with Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Зонтик logical suspection since it works great with my firefox. But they are so many users facing the same and as I mentioned I've not make any changes towards Chrome and reset default settings.

Comment: I created a new Firefox profile and it worked for a week. And then it came back to the original problem.

Comment: Worst CX ever. I usually stop using a service after getting out logged out. But stackoverflow has monopoly on code knowled 